# Installing Python libraries in AWS EMR Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to use my oft-used python libraries, such as numpy, pandas, and matplotlib, as well as other libraries like scikit-learn and PySpark on a Jupyter Notebook that is connected to an EMR cluster (PySpark kernel).

**Part 1: Wrong Numpy Version**

The problem arises when I run this cell:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

error message:

```
this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.17.3
your numpy version is 1.16.5.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.17.3 to use this pandas version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    f"this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < {_min_numpy_ver}\n"
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.17.3
your numpy version is 1.16.5.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.17.3 to use this pandas version
```

I tried installing the latest version, along with all my other desired libraries, in a bootstrap action as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo pip3 install -U \
pyspark \
scikit-learn \
scipy \
boto3 \
wordcloud \
seaborn \
matplotlib \
plotly \
pandas \
numpy
```

After the bootstrap action is complete and the cluster is ready, I check the available libraries by running:

```
sc.list_packages()
```

and I get this:

```
aws-cfn-bootstrap (2.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.9.1)
boto (2.49.0)
boto3 (1.22.2)
botocore (1.25.2)
click (7.1.2)
cycler (0.11.0)
docutils (0.14)
fonttools (4.33.3)
jmespath (0.10.0)
joblib (0.16.0)
kiwisolver (1.4.2)
lockfile (0.11.0)
lxml (4.5.2)
matplotlib (3.5.1)
mysqlclient (1.4.2)
nltk (3.5)
nose (1.3.4)
numpy (1.21.6)
packaging (21.3)
pandas (1.3.5)
Pillow (9.1.0)
pip (9.0.1)
plotly (5.7.0)
py-dateutil (2.2)
py4j (0.10.9.3)
pyparsing (3.0.8)
pyspark (3.2.1)
pystache (0.5.4)
python-daemon (2.2.3)
python-dateutil (2.8.2)
python37-sagemaker-pyspark (1.4.0)
pytz (2020.1)
PyYAML (5.3.1)
regex (2020.7.14)
s3transfer (0.5.2)
scikit-learn (1.0.2)
scipy (1.7.3)
seaborn (0.11.2)
setuptools (28.8.0)
simplejson (3.2.0)
six (1.13.0)
soupsieve (1.9.5)
tenacity (8.0.1)
threadpoolctl (3.1.0)
tqdm (4.48.2)
typing-extensions (4.2.0)
urllib3 (1.26.9)
wheel (0.29.0)
windmill (1.6)
wordcloud (1.8.1)
```

Note that here, numpy's version is 1.21.6, which should have resolved the error saying I needed numpy >= 1.17.3.

But when I run the imports, they still throw the same error, saying that my numpy version is 1.16.5.

My understanding from reading other posts is that bootstrap action occurs BEFORE the final steps of the cluster creation, so my numpy installation gets overwritten by the system default version of 1.16.5 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

**How can I resolve this compatibility issue between numpy and other libraries?**

**Part 2: No module named 'pyspark.pandas'**

I want to use the Pandas API in PySpark library. So, I tried doing this:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
```

and got the following error:

```
No module named 'pyspark.pandas'
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.pandas'
```

This works fine, however:

```
import pyspark
```

**How can I resolve this error?**

Lastly, I tried reconfiguring the cluster by submitting reconfiguration request and applying it to all nodes.

```
[
  {
     "Classification": "spark-env",
     "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Applying this request did not help, however.

-My EMR cluster specifications-

Release label: emr-5.31.1

Hadoop distribution: Amazon 2.10.0

Applications: Hive 2.3.7, JupyterHub 1.1.0, Spark 2.4.6

and I am signed in as root user.

Comment: This was a known bug and more can be found on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406738/aws-emr-pandas-conflict-with-numpy-in-pyspark-after-bootstrapping


the solution is to install `pandas=1.2.5` which would force numpy to be install >= 1.17.3

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, even when I set the pandas version to be 1.2.5 in the bootstrap script, the numpy version that emr installs is unaffected - it remains 1.16.5. As a result, I still run into the version incompatibility error. Have you (or anyone) had this issue?

Comment: yeah experienced the same , do not additionally install `numpy` , that would anyways be installed with `pandas` as a dependency

Comment: Can you do `sc.install_pypi_package("pandas==1.2.5")` and let me know if any of the above resolve with this? I will convert it to answer, if it works.